# How can I install Terminfo for GNU Screen on Termux to run Emacs?

Tags: termux

When I ssh from my system to termux, my term is

```
~ $ echo $TERM
screen.xterm-256color
```

..and I can't start Emacs.

Seems Termux doesn't like that. If I change it to

```
$ export TERM=xterm-256color
```

, then all is good.

Do I need to install terminfo for GNU Screen to be able to run Emacs?

Comment: I think this is probably a question better asked on super user, because I think it's a question about Linux and terminfo and valid TERM values, but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a question about termux and terminfo rather than Emacs, so I will be brief.

The terminfo database is normally stored in `/usr/share/terminfo`. For example, the entry for `screen.xterm-256color` would be in the file called `/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen.xterm-256color`.

You can use the `infocmp` program to show what is in these files. Check the man page for details, but if you give it a terminal name it will print out everything it knows about it. It sounds like in your current setup `infocmp xterm-256color` will succeed while `infocmp screen.xterm-256color` will give you an error. See the man page for more details, obviously.

The command `tic` compiles a terminfo file from it’s source code, if you happen to find it and don’t have a better way to install it. Again, read the man page if you have any questions.

I don’t know anything specific about Termux, so I cannot tell you how to install things with it; you will have to consult it’s own documentation. Know however that `screen.xterm-256color` is a very normal terminal name to use; it should be in your terminfo database if it is installed correctly. Usually you install the entire database from a single OS package and you don’t have to mess about with individual entries unless you have installed a brand new terminal emulator.